# Timestamps in the questions list are odd

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app, timestamps, question-lists

Timestamps in Android App v1.0.50 currently don't make sense, and aren't actually conveying the last activity.

Note the timestamps here, considering this is sorted as *Active.* You can click this for a full view.

[image]

Compared to the timestamps on the main site:

[image]

This has been consistently reproducible all morning. (Not sure if it's been occurring previously, I only noticed it today after someone's edit dug up a post from 2012.)

This is on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Comment: I'd guess it's showing when the questions were asked, not last modified.

Comment: This appears to have been resolved within the last few hours.